# Cambiar el formato hora del Time Picker de Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-timepicker

Como puedo incluir el `0` en el horario del la mañanas, por defecto me sale:

```
8:00:00
9:30:00
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que el horarios muestre así:

```
08:00:00
09:30:00
```

¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formato de la hora del [timepicker de Bootstrap](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker) para que se muestre con un 0 delante si es menos de 10?

Éste es el código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fechaInicio').timepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'HH:mm:ss',
    minuteStep: 1,
    showSeconds: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    icons: {
      up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
      down: 'fa fa-chevron-down'
    }
  }).on('focus', function() {
    $('#fechaInicio').timepicker('showWidget');
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<input id="fechaInicio" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 2):

El plugin no tiene ninguna opción aparente (al menos no ninguna listada en la documentación) para hacer que el resultado tenga el formato HH:mm:ss.

Un modo algo *hacky* de solucionarlo sería cambiar el funcionamiento por defecto del plugin. Por ejemplo, mirando el código del plugin puedes ver que la hora se escribe dentro del método `getTime` ([se ve mejor en la versión sin minificar](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js)):

```
getTime: function() {
  if (this.hour === '') {
    return '';
  }

  return this.hour + ':' + (this.minute.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.minute : this.minute) + (this.showSeconds ? ':' + (this.second.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.second : this.second) : '') + (this.showMeridian ? ' ' + this.meridian : '');
}
```

En esa función, si los minutos son menos de 10 (tienen una longitud igual a 1) entonces se les añade un 0 delante... pero no se hace lo mismo con las horas. Podrías aplicar el mismo código que añade el 0 en los minutos pero a las horas:

```
getTime: function() {
  if (this.hour === '') {
    return '';
  }
  return (this.hour.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.hour : this.hour) + ':' + (this.minute.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.minute : this.minute) + (this.showSeconds ? ':' + (this.second.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.second : this.second) : '') + (this.showMeridian ? ' ' + this.meridian : '');
}
```

Ahora, no digo que reescribas el fichero del plugin original (algo que no recomiendo), pero puedes redefinir alguna parte una vez que se haya cargado. Así podrías redefinir el método `getTime` de la siguiente forma:

```
$.fn.timepicker.Constructor.prototype.getTime = function() {
  if (this.hour === '') {
    return '';
  }
  return (this.hour.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.hour : this.hour) + ':' + (this.minute.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.minute : this.minute) + (this.showSeconds ? ':' + (this.second.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.second : this.second) : '') + (this.showMeridian ? ' ' + this.meridian : '');
}
```

Y ya pone las horas con dos dígitos siempre, como puedes ver aquí:

> Nota: esto sólo funciona en el `input` de la fecha y no en el popup/widget que aparece. Si quieres que también lo haga en el widget deberías redefinir el método `updateWidget` también... aunque después de tantas modificaciones quizás sería mejor sugerir esos cambios en el git del plugin.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.timepicker.Constructor.prototype.getTime = function() {
    if (this.hour === '') {
      return '';
    }
    return (this.hour.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.hour : this.hour) + ':' + (this.minute.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.minute : this.minute) + (this.showSeconds ? ':' + (this.second.toString().length === 1 ? '0' + this.second : this.second) : '') + (this.showMeridian ? ' ' + this.meridian : '');
  }

  $('#fechaInicio').timepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: 'HH:mm:ss',
    minuteStep: 1,
    showSeconds: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    icons: {
      up: 'fa fa-chevron-up',
      down: 'fa fa-chevron-down'
    }
  }).on('focus', function() {
    $('#fechaInicio').timepicker('showWidget');
  });



});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>

<input id="fechaInicio" class="form-control" />
```